# How do I count number of occurences in Django?

Tags: django, orm

Here are models in my project:

```
class Tournament(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Start date")
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="End date")
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Participant)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.title


class Game(models.Model):

    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament)
    number_of_tour = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    opponent_white = models.ForeignKey(Participant, related_name='opponent_white', blank=True)
    opponent_black = models.ForeignKey(Participant, related_name='opponent_black', blank=True)
    winner = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=(('White', 'White'), ('Black', 'Black'), ('Draw', 'Draw')), blank=True)
    elo_gained_white = models.FloatField(default=0)
    elo_gained_black = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

My problem is that i want to know number of tours in each tournament. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
num_of_tours = Game.objects.filter(tournament=tournament_id).annotate(Count('number_of_tour', distinct=True)).count()
```

But this still returns number of Game objects related to a tournament with tournament_id. Could you show me the way to do it right?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the ugly parts of Django ORM ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the solution:

What he is looking for is the distinct count of number_of_tours per tournament.
Each game has a tour value, but those values can be double. so number_of_tours work like some kind of id.

Nervosa you can get the distinct value like so:

```
num_of_tours = Game.objects.filter(tournament=tournament_id).values('number_of_tour').distinct().count()
```

This should give you just that: the distinct number_of_tours per tournament

Answer (score 0):

So you want to `Sum` the `number_of_tour` column for all games in a specific tournament? I think you may need `aggregate` instead of `annotate` and `Sum` instead of `Count`:

```
num_of_tours = Game.objects.filter(tournament=tournament_id).aggregate(total_num=Sum('number_of_tour', distinct=True))['total_num']
```

EDIT: Daniel Roseman pointed out that `number_of_tour` is probably an index. That makes much more sense. My bad. You will need to do a distinct on the whole query, then count that query. Like this:

```
num_of_tours = Game.objects.filter(tournament=tournament_id).distinct('number_of_tour').count()
```

That should count the number of Game objects that have a different `number_of_tour`. I believe that is what you want. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This sums values of "number_of_tour" field. I want to know HOW MANY TOURS are there in a tournament. For example, there is a tournament with 3 Game objects where number_of_tour is 1, 3 Game objects where number_of_tour is 2 and 1 Game object where number_of_tour is 3. The result oа a query should be three. With your advice it is 12.

Comment: can you give us the query string that is created?

Comment: I'm really confused. what is a tour? You're saying there are 7 game objects in a tournament. Each game object has a different `number_of_tours`. So what is a tour? Where do you get the 3 for expected result? Do you want whatever the max `number_of_tour` is?

Comment: @jproffitt I think "number_of_tour" is meant as an index, not a count: ie "this is tour number 3".

Comment: @jproffitt: I really like your answer with the .distinct('number_of_tour') part, but keep in mind it is only compatible with Postgres. Won't work with mysql or sqlite and we don't know which db he is using

Comment: True. I'm just so used to Postgres now. Why wouldn't you use postgres? haha

Comment: With the question title + the poorly named field `number_of_tour` I can see where the confusion came from :)